# How to view the types of objects inside a collection with the Eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, collections

Does anyone know of a way to view the type (fully qualified or simple class name would be great) of the entries in a collection while debugging with Eclipse ?

[image]

If not can anyone recommend a plugin maybe or an easy way to do it while debugging (other than adding a watch expression like `collection.iterator().next().getClass()`) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also right click on the collection item in the Variables view and just choose Open Declared/Actual Type from the dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [detail formatter](http://www.robertwloch.net/2012/01/eclipse-tips-tricks-detail-formatter/).

With a detail formatter you can define how a specific type should be displayed in the eclipse debugger.

Just right click on the variable and select *New Detail Formatter* or manage them through *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Detail Formatters*